# Fill random data attributes to shapefile using FME?

Tags: random, fme-form

there are 150 shape layers and I want to fill the random data in attribute table having different types of fields as Character, integer and float, etc. Each layer have 5 to 15 fields.

Is this is possible to fill random data in all layers using fme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate random numbers for sure using the [RandomNumberGenerator](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/randomnumbergenerator.htm) transformer. It could create either integers or floats.

Characters are a bit more difficult. There's no random generator for that. You could either use the RandomNumberGenerator to generate character codes and convert them to ASCII using the [CharacterCodeReplacer](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/charactercodereplacer.htm), or you could try and find a web service that generates random strings and hit it with the HTTPCaller. There's [this site](https://www.random.org/strings/), which I believe has an API.

Alternatively, use the PythonCaller and use a little bit of Python code to generate random strings.